# Multiple graphs on the same page (chartjs), constructor/prototype pattern code organization

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Hi I am testing the situation where multiple graphs/charts are on the same page, currently I have 2 for testing purposes but will have more later. that said, I use constructor/prototype pattern and while graphs are shown on the page once clicked on the button and there are no errors I would like to know if I am organizing the code properly.

here is the code sample

```
var showGraphs = (function () {

function showGraphs () {
}

//grahp1
var ctx1 = document.getElementById("myGraph1").getContext("2d");
var data1 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};


//graph2
var ctx = document.getElementById("myGraph2").getContext("2d");
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var randomColorFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
};
var randomColor = function(opacity) {
    return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
};

var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
            label: 'Dataset 1'
        }, {
            hidden: true,
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
            label: 'Dataset 2'
        }, {
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
            label: 'Dataset 3'
        }],
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Grey",
            "Dark Grey"
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        }
    }
};


showGraphs.prototype.myAllGraphs = function () {

    //graph1
    var myGraph1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1
    });

    //graph2
    var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);

}

return showGraphs;


})();

var graphs = new showGraphs ();
$("#testButton").on("click",graphs.myAllGraphs);
```

here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dj1v5hr7/3/)

please tell me if there is something wrong with code organization.

Answer (score 0):

1- I would extract the data to a different file. It removes clutter on this file and can be reused elsewhere

2- As for the 2 buttons, you could just have `showGraphs` take a parameter to define which graph you should show i.e.:

```
    $("#testButton").on("click", graphs.myAllGraphs.bind(null, 1));

    showGraphs.prototype.myAllGraphs = function (graphNumber) {

    switch(graphNumber) {
      case 1:
        var myGraph1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: data1
        });
        break;
      case 2:
        var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
        break;
      default:
        var myGraph1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: data1
        });
        break;

    }

}
```